# Difference between Azure ASM and Azure ARM?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-resource-manager

Can someone tell me if ASM is retiring and What is ARM?. I saw many speculations on internet about ASM going to be deprecated. How will this affect my existing Azure Registered Apps?

I have gone through multiple Docs of Azure but still no clear explanation can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-faq) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/classic-vm-deprecation) Azure documents, Azure Service Manager (ASM) is the old control plane of Azure responsible for creating, managing, deleting VMs and performing other control plane operations whereas Azure Resource Manager (ARM) is the latest control plane of Azure responsible for creating, managing, deleting VMs and performing other control plane operations. For more information with regards to it, please refer the documents mentioned.

[image]

[image]